# Problem installing php-gettext-gettext package on Centos 9

Tags: centos, gettext

I tried several options to install `php-gettext-gettext` package.

```
 dnf install php-gettext-gettext
```

also

```
 dnf --enablerepo=remi install php-gettext-gettext
```

but there is no such package in these repositories.

How can I install `php-gettext-gettext` package on Centos 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package that provides gettext in CentOS 9 is `php-common` and is available in the Appstream repo. In CentOS 9, There is no need for Remi unless installing `php-gettext-languages`. The package `php-gettext-gettext was provided by Remi in CentOS 8 as well as RHEL 8, Alma Linux 8, and Rocky Linux 8 and is also available in the latest releases of Fedora.

Comment: Is your answer valid for Rocky Linux 9?

Comment: @Paramore Yes. It is also the case for Alma Linux 9 and Rocky Linux 9. Both packages are available in Fedora 38 and 39.